# import sequence from dump file in oracle

Tags: oracle

I am trying to import a sequence from a dump  file using the command since I am using Windows:

```
impdp hr DIRECTORY=user_exp DUMPFILE=morder.dmp include=sequence:\"= 'EMPLOYEES'\"
```

However,it gave me error:

```
UDI-000257: operation generated Oracle error 257
ORA-00257 archiver error,connect internal only when freed
```

Need some guidance here please

Comment: That error generally has nothing to do with an import.  It implies that your database is running in archivelog mode but your archiver process isn't running.  That's something the DBA needs to resolve.

Comment: thanks! I resolved that issue.Now I am getting the error that "hr.Employees" already exists.Could I be importing to incorrect username/schema? I am importing everything from hr to hr1.

Comment: How are you causing everything to be imported into hr1?  That's not obvious from the command line in the question

Comment: i know.I imported tables individually (forgot the import command i had used).Now I need to import only the sequence.So ran into this issue after executing above command